# Difference between git pull --rebase and git pull --ff-only

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

Let's say `origin/master` has commit `A--B--C` and my `local/master` has commit `A--B--D`.

What will happen if I use `git pull --rebase` ?

What will happen if I use `git pull --ff-only` ?

Is there any difference in the resulting commit tree ?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

> What will happen if I use git pull --rebase ?

`git pull --rebase` is roughly equivalent to

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

i.e. your remote changes (`C`) will be applied before the local changes (`D`), resulting in the following tree

```
A -- B -- C -- D
```

---

> What will happen if I use git pull --ff-only ?

It will fail.

`git pull --ff-only` corresponds to

```
git fetch
git merge --ff-only origin/master
```

`--ff-only` applies the remote changes only if they can be fast-forwarded. From the man:

> Refuse to merge and exit with a non-zero status unless the current HEAD is already up-to-date or the merge can be resolved as a fast-forward

Since your local and remote branches have diverged, they cannot be resolved by a fast-forward and `git pull --ff-only` would fail.

Comment: What would happen if there is no commit `D` in local change ? Would both command be equivalent ?

Comment: Yes, they would both result in `A--B--C`.

Comment: what would `git pull --rebase --ff-only` do? (assuming there are C & D)

Comment: IIRC the --ff-only option simply gets ignored when paired with --rebase

Comment: Why would anybody want to use this `--ff-only` ? It defeats the purpose of git pull.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin it's useful if you want to guarantee a linear history. By default `pull` can introduce merge commits, whereas you may prefer working with rebase and ff only.

Comment: So if `local/master` has history `A--B` (no `D` commit), effectively `--rebase` and `--ff-only` would result equally?

Comment: @BernardoDalCorno Yes!

Comment: Is there any benefit using `--ff-only` other than reviewing the changes clean by forcing the user to stash before he can pull in case of working changes?

Comment: bit late to this answer but wouldn't `--ff-only` only fail if the merge can't be resolved cause of a merge conflict? and if `C` and `D` don't conflict, I don't see why a `--ff-only` would fail.