# What does git pull --rebase --ff-only do?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull

I saw a command line reference which recommended `git pull --rebase --ff-only`. I thought git would reject that, but it doesn’t.

What does the combination of `--rebase` with `--ff-only` mean?

*Edit:* I perfectly know what each alone does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between git pull --rebase and git pull --ff-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430600/difference-between-git-pull-rebase-and-git-pull-ff-only)

Comment: No, that's not a duplicate. It's the combination of `--rebase` and `--ff-only` passed to `git pull` this is about.

Comment: Maybe the recommendation should be either rebase or --ff-only because the default behavior makes merge commits automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit, 4 Dec 2016: as of Git version 2.6, `git pull` is no longer a script, so it is no longer easy to see what it does and the technical details below no longer apply.  But `--ff-only` is still only useful when merging, not when rebasing.]

The `git pull` script (you can view it yourself, e.g., `less $(git --exec-path)/pull`) currently separates out `--ff-only` into a variable named `$ff_only` that it subsequently ignores entirely if it winds up doing a rebase:

```
case "$rebase" in
true)
        eval="git-rebase $diffstat $strategy_args $merge_args $rebase_args $verbosity"
        eval="$eval $gpg_sign_args"
        eval="$eval --onto $merge_head ${oldremoteref:-$merge_head}"
        ;;
*)
        eval="git-merge $diffstat $no_commit $verify_signatures $edit $squash $no_ff $ff_only"
        eval="$eval $log_arg $strategy_args $merge_args $verbosity $progress"
        eval="$eval $gpg_sign_args"
        eval="$eval FETCH_HEAD"
        ;;
esac
eval "exec $eval"
```

What this means in the end is that your `--ff-only` option gets ignored.

It's possible that in the future, git might reject these as incompatible, so it's probably wiser to leave out an explicit `--ff-only` when using an explicit `--rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `--ff-only` will be ignored when using `--rebase`.