# Difference between `git pull --rebase --autostash` and `git pull --ff-only`?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

Following question [Can “git pull” automatically stash and pop pending changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208928/can-git-pull-automatically-stash-and-pop-pending-changes) has solutions using both:

- `git pull --rebase --autostash`
- `git pull --ff-only`

I am little bit confused about which one should I use. Do they actually accomplish same result? Very similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25430600/2402577) is asked which does not has `--autostash` parameter along with the `--rebase`

Comment: `git pull --ff-only` can success only if local or remote has changed, if there is commit on both local and remote this will trigger an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine a situation where the remote has changes you don't:

```
remote | A - B - C - D - E
       |
local  | A - B - C
```

Here you can `git pull --ff-only`, because it's possible to fast-forward from `C` to `E`. Now imagine you've also made changes:

```
remote | A - B - C - D - E
       |
local  | A - B - C - F - G
```

If you `git pull --ff-only`, it will be rejected, because you can't fast-forward from `G` to `E`; per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---ff) (emphasis mine):

> With `--ff-only`, resolve the merge as a fast-forward when possible.
> **When not possible, refuse to merge** and exit with a non-zero status.

There are two ways to solve this, either:

- creating a merge commit (the default if a fast-forward isn't possible, or can be forced with `--no-ff`); or
- rebasing (`--rebase`).

If you `git pull --rebase`, it will roll your local copy back to `C`, fast-forward to `E`, then replay `F` and `G` onto the new parent, leaving:

```
remote | A - B - C - D - E
       |
local  | A - B - C - D - E - F' - G'
```

---

`--autostash` is a *separate* argument, per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---autostash):

> This means that you can run the operation on a dirty worktree.

In both cases above I assumed a clean worktree (i.e. `git status` shows *"nothing to commit, working tree clean"* - you have no uncommitted local changes), for simplicity's sake, but sometimes you might want to pull new changes while you have local work in progress.